# Script to list all files each time I change directory for bashrc?

Tags: linux

I would like to list all files each time I execute the "change directory" command.

I have already tried adding this to my ~/.bashrc:

```
function cdl { cd $1; ls;}
```

and running this in terminal:

```
cdl directorytoswitchto
```

Long story short: I would like to do `cd` and `ls` in the same command.

Comment: So what's the problem?   `cdl` seems to do what you want.

Comment: But you should probably do `cdl() { cd "$@" && ls; }`.  Or perhaps you're looking to replace `cd` with `cd() { command cd "$@" && ls; }`

Comment: Or perhaps you just need to re-read your .bashrc to make `cdl` work.  (eg, logout and login, or execute `exec bash`, or execute `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: This worked: ```cd() { command cd "$@" && ls; }``` Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To override a builtin function with a different version, you typically will call the original via `command`. For example,

```
cd() { command cd "$@" && ls; }
```